# How to limit index length in SOLR for a single field

Tags: solr

I added this to my chain

```
<processor class="solr.TruncateFieldUpdateProcessorFactory">
    <str name="typeClass">solr.TextField</str>
    <int name="maxLength">250</int>
</processor>
```

but I know this will be applied on indexing to all fields with fieldType class = solr.TextField, and I have several using that. Is there a way to apply it to a single field?

thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The field mutating processors [supports four selector parameters](https://github.com/apache/lucene-solr/blob/master/solr/core/src/java/org/apache/solr/update/processor/FieldMutatingUpdateProcessorFactory.java#L46) by default:

> `fieldName` - selecting specific fields by field name lookup
>
> `fieldRegex` - selecting specific fields by field name regex match (regexes are checked in the order specified)
>
> `typeName` - selecting specific fields by fieldType name lookup
>
> `typeClass` - selecting specific fields by fieldType class lookup, including inheritence and interfaces

So to only affect a single field:

```
<str name="fieldName">name_of_field</str>
```

> Each criteria can specified as either an <arr> of <str>, or multiple <str> with the same name.  When multiple criteria of a single type exist, fields must match **at least one** to be selected. If more then one type of criteria exist, fields must match at least one of each to be selected.
>
> ...
>
> One or more `excludes` <lst> params may also be specified, containing any of the above criteria, identifying fields to be excluded from seelction even if they match the selection criteria.

Comment: Thanks. I was trying using fields and getting an error but this works. Do you know if this affects the indexing only or it will also return my field truncated? I am going to find out this but reindexing will take a few hours...

Comment: Any processor will run before the field sees the content, so it'll be truncated for storage as well. If you only want to truncate the tokens (sent to indexing), you can use the [`TruncateTokenFilter`](https://wiki.apache.org/solr/AnalyzersTokenizersTokenFilters#solr.TruncateTokenFilterFactory).